# Editing The TSWebPart

Tags: web-part

I have got the WebAccessPart working in Sharepoint as a way for out users to run our business apps. I would like to be able to set the value of both check boxes to be true by default (the optimize lan experience and using private computer), and also hide them so the user never has to deal with them.

I have managed to hide them by editing the XML for the web part and adding these keys:

```
<property name="ShowOptimizeExperience" type="bool">False</property>
<property name="ShowPublicCheckBox" type="bool">False</property>
```

This does the job of hiding them, but i cant find a way to set the values to true. Anyone any ideas?

Also, i would like it so the user never gets prompted for a password when running an app. I can make it so it passes the user, and once they put the password in once it remembers it for the session, but i'd like it never to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got round the ticking of the boxes by using some javascript on the page to set the value of the text box after the page had loaded